# What does a player get after defeat the Boss Monster in area 11, 12 and 13?

Tags: mini-rogue

In the Mini Rogue game, when a player encounters a boss monster and defeats it, he/she gets a reward that is mentioned at the boss monster card based on the level in each area. In front of level 5, the reward is "OG's Blood".

So as I understand, I get the OG's Blood after passing area 14. But what do I get in level 5 other areas like 11, 12 and 13 after killing the boss monster?

Should I continue in area 11, 12 and 13 of level 5 without any reward for killing the boss monster?

[image]

Comment: In the ["latest"](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/131999/mini-rogue-cards-and-rules) version of the rules this card looks somewhat differently.

Comment: The way I read the rules it is not possible to encounter boss monster before the last area of a level.